# EDT violation for using EncodedImage.createFromImage method

Tags: codenameone

I'm using the following line in code in JSON buildRequestBody(OutputStream os) method will throwing saying EDT violation. Please advise if there is any wrong in using this. Please see the attached log.

Code:

```
if (a.getSign() != null) {
body
+= ",\n           \"SignatureData\": \n"
+ "           {\n"
+ "            \"SignatureImage\": \"" + Base64.encodeNoNewline(EncodedImage.createFromImage(a.getSignature(), false).getImageData()) + "\"\n"
+ "           }\n";
} else {
body += "\n";
}
```

Log:

```
at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.checkEDT(JavaSEPort.java:699)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.getImageWidth(JavaSEPort.java:4744)
at com.codename1.ui.Image.getWidth(Image.java:690)
at com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.createFromImage(EncodedImage.java:164)   com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperation(ConnectionRequest.java:689)
at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:282)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort$EDTViolation: EDT Violation Stack!
at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.checkEDT(JavaSEPort.java:699)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.JavaSEPort.getImageHeight(JavaSEPort.java:4755)
at com.codename1.ui.Image.getHeight(Image.java:704)
at com.codename1.ui.EncodedImage.createFromImage(EncodedImage.java:165)
at com.codename1.io.ConnectionRequest.performOperation(ConnectionRequest.java:689)
at com.codename1.io.NetworkManager$NetworkThread.run(NetworkManager.java:282)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

Answer (score 0):

`EncodedImage` performs a borderline EDT violation on purpose for performance. The EDT violation code sends a false positive because we don't know the difference.

This is OK and doesn't cause a problem on the devices.